# Problems with using delphi dta types with a C DLL

Tags: matlab, delphi, dll

I am trying to use a .dll which has been written in C (although it wraps around a matlab .ddl)

The function I am trying to use is defined in C as:

```
 __declspec(dllexport) int ss_scaling_subtraction(double* time, double** signals, double* amplitudes, int nSamples, int nChannels, double* intensities);
```

The .dll requires, amongst others, a 2 dimensional array - When I tried to use:

```
Array of array of double
```

In the declaration, the compiler gave an error so I defined my own data type:

```
T2DArray = Array of array of double;
```

I initialise the .dll function in a unit like so:

```
 function ss_scaling_subtraction(const time: array of double; const signals: T2DArray; const amplituides : array of double; const nSamples: integer;const nChannels: integer; var intensities: array of double) : integer ; cdecl; external 'StirScanDLL.dll';
```

However, when called this function, I get an access violation from the .dll

Creating a new data type

```
T1DArray = array of double
```

and changing

```
Array of double
```

To

```
T1DArray
```

In the declaration seems to make things run but the result is still not correct.

I have read on here that it can be dangerous to pass delphi data types to .dll's coded in a different language so I thought this might be causing the issue.

But how do I NOT use a delphi data type when I HAVE to use it to properly declare the function in the first place?!

Extra Info, I have already opened the matlab runtime complier lib's and opened the entry point to the StirScanDLL.dll

Comment: Dynamic arrays are never safe for interop. Question is pointless without the other side of the interop boundary.

Comment: What makes them us safe, what can I do to make them safe, I set the length before passing them into the function if that helps.

Comment: Also, creating a T1DArray data type seemed to make it run, but I still doing think its doing its thing correctly.

Comment: Confirmed, creating a new data type does stop the exception. But I dont think the .dll in running properly.

Comment: Sorry, David, what is an " interop boundary" ?

Comment: The full error message was : Project DemoApp.exe raised exception class EAcessViolation with message "Access Violation at address 73971138 in module 'StirScanDLL.dll" Read of address 04014000. Process stopped.

Comment: __declspec(dllexport) int ss_scaling_subtraction(double* time, double** signals, double* amplitudes, int nSamples, int nChannels, double* intensities);

Comment: I assume this is it, I was passed the .dll by someone else and this is the documentation he gave me.

Comment: OK, these edits are good. We are nearly there. The interop boundary is the boundary between the two modules that are interoperating. You call a function from Delphi, the function thayt executes is coded in a different language. There's no type safety as you cross interop boundary. What we need now is an idea of what the dimensions of the 2D array are.

Comment: the dimensions are 1001 by 8 doubles

Comment: I have tried flipping the dimensions, with no result.

Comment: I don't mean the sizes. I mean what does each dimension represent. Is the major dimension channels or samples?

Comment: The major (and by that I assume you mean largest, and first) is Samples. The second is channels. Out of interest, these were the names given in the documentation (which I though was a strange thing to call them, well channels anyway, because they are recordings from the same channel in the electronics sense), is this computer speak I don't know?

Comment: Again, out of interest, what does this information tell you? I just see it as a 2D matrix of values, the representations being unimportant...

Comment: The representation is everything here. The two sides of the interop boundary must use a common representation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The basic problem here is one of binary interop mismatch. Simply put, a pointer to an array is not the same thing at a binary level as a Delphi open array parameter. Whilst they both semantically represent an array, the binary representation differs.

The C function is declared as follows:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int ss_scaling_subtraction(
    double* time, 
    double** signals, 
    double* amplitudes, 
    int nSamples, 
    int nChannels, 
    double* intensities
);
```

Declare your function like so in Delphi:

```
function ss_scaling_subtraction(
    time: PDouble; 
    signals: PPDouble; 
    amplitudes: PDouble; 
    nSamples: Integer;
    nChannels: Integer; 
    intensities: PDouble
): Integer; cdecl; external 'StirScanDLL.dll';
```

If you find that `PPDouble` is not declared, define it thus:

```
type
  PPDouble = ^PDouble;
```

That is, pointer to pointer to double.

Now what remains is to call the functions. Declare your arrays in Delphi as dynamic arrays. Like this:

```
var
  time, amplitudes, intensities: TArray<Double>; 
  signals: TArray<TArray<Double>>;
```

If you have an older pre-generics Delphi then declare some types:

```
type
  TDoubleArray = array of Double;
  T2DDoubleArray = array of TDoubleArray;
```

Then declare the variables with the appropriate types.

Next you need to allocate the arrays, and populate any that have data passing from caller to callee.

```
SetLength(time, nSamples); // I'm guessing here as to the length
SetLength(signals, nSamples, nChannels); // again, guessing
```

Finally it is time to call the function. Now it turns out that the good designers of Delphi arranged for dynamic arrays to be stored as pointers to the first element. That means that they are a simple cast away from being used as parameters.

```
retval := ss_scaling_subtraction(
   PDouble(time),
   PPDouble(signals),
   PDouble(amplitudes),
   nSamples,
   nChannels,
   PDouble(intensities)
);
```

Note that the casting of the dynamic arrays seen here does rely on an implementation detail. So, some people might argue that it would be better to use, for instance `@time[0]` and so on for the one dimensional arrays. And to create an array of `PDouble` for the amplitudes and copy over the addresses of the first elements of the inner arrays. Personally I am comfortable with relying on this implementation detail. It certainly makes the coding a lot simpler.

---

One final piece of advice. Interop can be tricky. It's easy to get wrong. When you get it wrong, the code compiles, but then dies horribly at runtime. With cryptic error messages. Leading to much head scratching.

So, start with the simplest possible interface. A function that receives scalar parameters. Say, receives an integer, and returns an integer. Prove that you can do that. Then move on to floating point scalars. Then one dimensional arrays. Finally two dimensional arrays. Each step along the way, build up the complexity. When you hit a problem you'll know that it is down to the most recently added parameter.

You've not taken that approach. You've gone straight for the kill and implemented everything in your first attempt. And when it fails, you've no idea where to look. Break a problem into small pieces, and build the more complex problem out of those smaller pieces.

Comment: Thank you very Much David, I was reading an answer you gave to a similar question, I am sure this will be exactly what I need. Thank you for your time and patience. (As you might have guessed) I am an electronics engineer by trade and this is all very new to me. Again, thank you for your time.

Comment: I added some more general advice. This is really the most important thing I can offer you.

Comment: @tim-mottram;  Pardon my curiosity, but any particular reason why you haven't accepted DavidH's answer?  It looks like thorough sound advice to me and has attracted 8 upvotes so far.

Comment: I will be accepting the answer when I have coded it up and made sure that it works, I am sure it will but I have to make sure, if only to keep the forum solid. I would have done it on the spot but it was around 7.30pm on a Friday and the sun was shining!

Comment: All sorted now, working find and dandy. Thanks for your help David.